# GCD Proof to find all integers that satisfy $am + bn = \gcd(a, b)$

Tags: proof-writing, gcd-and-lcm

I have this question that I'm not entirely sure how to answer.

> Suppose that $a, b$ are non-zero integers. Find all integers $m, n$
>    such that $am + bn = \gcd(a, b)$

I know that it suffices to show that if $m, n$ and $m', n'$ are 2 possible solutions that showing that $\frac{b}{\gcd(a, b)}\mid m-m'$ and $\frac{a}{\gcd(a, b)}\mid n-n'$. However, I'm not entirely sure how to get there. Thanks.

Comment: From $am + bn = am' + bn'$, obtain $a(m - m') = b(n' - n)$. It follows that $a \mid b(n'-n)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $c = \text{gcd}(a,b)$.

- Hint 1: Start with $am + bn = c$ and $am' + bn' = c$. What happens if you combine these equations?
- Hint 2: What is the value of $\text{gcd}(a/c, b/c)$?
- Hint 3: If $x \mid yz$ and $\text{gcd}(x,y) = 1$, what is the relationship between $x$ and $z$?

Comment: For hint 2, I'm not entirely sure... would it be 1?

Comment: Indeed: the intuition lies in the fact that $c$ is the _greatest_ common divisor of $a$ and $b$. If $\text{gcd}(a/c,b/c) = k > 1$, for example, it would imply that even though we divided both $a$ and $b$ by their greatest common divisor, they still have a common divisor $> 1$, which should seem wrong.